# Not able to see User Details in winter 14

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting `"Time Limit Exceeded"` while trying to see User details after winter 14 release. Is there any one else who is facing same issue?

Comment: Sandbox upgrade or pre-release org?

Comment: Sandbox Upgrade